# unable to get tracks for Discover Weekly rspotify gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spotify

I was trying to get the tracks under "Discover Weekly", But it says unauthorized access.

```
RestClient::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized from /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@<project>/gems/rest_client-1.8.2/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!'
```

In the playlist i am getting "Discover weekly" but when I try to search tracks for it, its causing this error.

Any help would be great!!

Comment: Do you send an access token along with your request? If so, has the access token expired? The HTTP response from the Web API has a JSON-formatted response body along with the 401 Unauthorized status code that'd help a lot when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the Discover Weekly list is private by default. Trying to access a private playlist with the gem will throw a 401. By making the playlist public and using `spotifydiscover` as the username, you can access the playlist via the API. For example:

```
RSpotify::Playlist.find('spotifydiscover', '4ri0zgl8aDgNv2zoVPbUFZ')
```